# Where does .jar file look for input files?

Tags: java, file-io, jar

I create a .jar file on my local computer (with ant/eclipse) then upload it to a server (foo/usr/share/java).  I want my .jar file to read in a file called "example.txt".  Where on my server do I need to save "example.txt" so that this happens?  Alternatively, how should I alter the filepath in my code? I am happy hardcoding this one filepath as neither the file nor filepath will change.  Thanks!

Comment: Generally, you should make the file name a command-line argument.

Answer (score 0):

If you running your application at console, then save your text file at **current** folder. If your application works inside application server, then file will be searched in current folder of application server.

Best way to open exact file you need - use program argument.

In the Java programming language, every application must contain a main method whose signature is:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

This array is the mechanism through which the runtime system passes information to your application. For example:

```
java MyApp arg1 arg2
```

Each string in the array is called a command-line argument. Command-line arguments let users affect the operation of the application without recompiling it.

Answer (score 0):

If you supply a relative pathname, it is relative to the user's current working directory when he executed the .jar file. If you provide an absolute filename, job done.

Answer (score -1):

You should put the file in the same directory as your .jar file and your program should find it, but as chrylis mentioned, a command-line argument is the best.

Comment: Your program *can* find it there, if it executes a statement about a yard long, but that's not where it looks by default.